# Difference Between Satchmo's local_settings.py and settings.py

Tags: python, django, satchmo

Can someone explain the difference between `local_settings.py` and `settings.py` in Satchmo?

I understand that the `settings.py` module imports the `local_settings.py` module as it's final step. So any settings in `local_settings.py` takes precedence. But what is the point of doing this? Isn't `settings.py` supposed to be the configuration which is specific to your project anyway? Why bother with the additional step of having `local_settings.py`?

Basically I find myself needing to add new settings and I can't figure out if I should put them in `settings.py` or `local_settings.py`. Can someone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `local_settings.py` is only for on your local development system where it extends `settings.py`. On your deployment server, `settings.py` is used only without `local_settings.py`.

One recommendation is that `local_settings.py` is not included in your repository, so that each developer can have their own and so that it is not used on the deployment server.

Checkout these articles for more information:

1. [Extending Django settings.py File](http://www.nerdydork.com/extending-django-settings-py-file.html)
2. [Extending Settings Variables with local_settings.py in Django](http://www.robgolding.com/blog/2010/05/03/extending-settings-variables-with-local_settings-py-in-django/)
3. [Django settings.py for development and production](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-settings)
4. [A Different Approach to local_settings.py](http://lethain.com/entry/2008/nov/28/a-different-approach-to-local_settings-py/)

Comment: That makes sense. I had assumed that `local_settings.py` was specific to the Satchmo project, but it seems as if it is actually a Django construct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that `settings.py` contains all the settings you actually need to run your project. `local_settings.py` is for if you need to override any of them locally, for instance in development. For example, you might have different database passwords, or template paths, etc.

The answer to your question is to put new settings into `settings.py`, though.